# Emoticons and chars like дей are broken while UInt8 conversion

Tags: javascript, encoding, typescript, webcrypto-api

i have the problem that I get JS-Objects with fields like ... title: "действительный有効なដែលមាន... or for example containing this emote . Now, due to encryption, I need to convert this information to UInt8.

The code that handles the conversion looks like this (and works properly in the general case ...)

```
    public arrayBufferToString(arrayBuffer : Uint8Array) : string {
        var str : string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
        return str;
    }

    public stringToArrayBuffer(string:string) : Uint8Array {
        if(typeof string === 'undefined' || string === null){
            this.$log.warn('Cannot convert an undefined string');
            return null;
        }

        var arrayBuffer : any = new ArrayBuffer(string.length);
        var buffer : Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        for (var i : number = 0, stringLength : number = string.length; i < stringLength; i++) {
            buffer[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

In these situations, however, I have an input like this:
"title":"действительный有効なដែលមានសុពលភាព有效有效માન્યમાבתוקף" and an output, after formatting it back to a string, like this
"title":"459AB28B5;L=K9 ¹jÂ¶»¶  H   H®¾¨Í¯®¾ÑêÕçã"

Do you have any idea why this happens? Thank you!

Comment: Your emoticons are character codes that do not fit in 8 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following scripts encrypts and decrypts `dataToEncrypt`. It uses modern [Encoding API](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-textdecoder-decode).

```
"use strict";

var dataToEncrypt = "дей ... hopefully, it means 'day' :)";
var iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
var algorithm = {
    name: "AES-CBC",
    iv: iv
};

window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "AES-CBC",
        length: 128
    },
    /* extractable */ true,
    /*keyUsages */ ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
).
then(function (aesKey) {
        var uint16array = new TextEncoder('utf-16').encode(dataToEncrypt);

        window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, aesKey, uint16array)
            .then(function (encryptedArrayBuffer) {

                console.log("encrypted", ab2hexstr(encryptedArrayBuffer));

                window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(algorithm, aesKey, encryptedArrayBuffer)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        console.log("decrypted", new TextDecoder('utf-16').decode(result));
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log("Decryption failed.", err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Encryption failed.", err);
            });
    }
).
catch(function (err) {
    console.log("generateKey - failed.", err);
});

function ab2hexstr(buf) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buf);
    var hexString = "";
    var nextHexByte;

    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
        nextHexByte = byteArray[i].toString(16);  // Integer to base 16
        if (nextHexByte.length < 2) {
            nextHexByte = "0" + nextHexByte;     // Otherwise 10 becomes just a instead of 0a
        }
        hexString += nextHexByte;
    }
    return hexString;
}
```

- [jsFiddle for the previous script](https://jsfiddle.net/hs8hmcow/)
- [jsFiddle for a version without Encoding API](https://jsfiddle.net/oz5qot9u/)

The scripts are based on [crypto.js](https://infotechinc.github.io/symmetric-encryption-in-browser/crypto.js).

**Note:**

I did not use TypeScript but you can add types as you like.

**Resources:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/encode
- https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/encoding-api/index.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt